# Is there a way to add a class name to a blazor component without overriding the existing class name?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Suppose I have a component, MyComponent, declared as follow:

```
<div class="container">
  "some nested content"
</div>
```

now I want to consume the component, and give it a class name:

```
<MyComponent class="new-class" />
```

If I do this, the "container" class name will be overridden by "new-class":

```
<div class="new-class">
  ....
<div>
```

Is there a way to keep both class names and have, at the end:

```
<div class="container new-class">
  ....
<div>
```

Comment: You said "the "container" class name will be overridden by "new-class"" but how? What happens in MyComponent that does that?

Comment: @Vencovsky i'm not sure but is it the RenderTreeBuilder ?

Comment: Try adding a string property to the inner component and add it to the class tag <div class="container @AdditionalClasses"> and use it on the parent <MyComponent AdditionalClasses="new-class" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to learn about "Component Parameters": `[Parameter]`. On your component, declare a parameter:

```
<div class="container @CssClass">
  "some nested content"
</div>

@code
{
   [Parameter] public string CssClass {get; set;} = "";
}
```

Now, when you use your component, if you want, you can set a value to the parameter:

```
<MyComponent CssClass="new-class" />
```

Quoting [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#component-parameters):

> Components can have component parameters, which are defined using public simple or complex properties on the component class with the [Parameter] attribute. Use attributes to specify arguments for a component in markup.